# backpropagation issues with a custom layer (TF/Keras)

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I've been working on a prototype and I am having issues with backpropagation.I am currently using the latest keras and tensorflow build ( as tensorflow as a backend, I have looked into cntk, mxnet, and chainer; so far  only chainer would allow me to do it but the training time is quite slow..)

My current layer is similar to a convolutional layer with more operations than a simple multiplication.

I know that tensorflow should use automatic differentiation if all the operations support it to calculate the gradient and perform gradient descent.

Currently my layer uses the following operator : reduce_sum, sum, subtraction, multiplication and division.

I also relies on the following methods: extract_image_patches, reshape, transpose.

I doubt any of these would cause an issue with automatic gradient descent. I built 2 layers as tests, one inherits from the base layer in keras while the other inherit directly from _Conv. In both cases whenever I use that layer anywhere in a model no weights are updated during the training process.

How could I solve this problem and fix backpropagation?

Edit:
(Here is the layer implementation https://github.com/roya0045/cvar2/blob/master/tfvar.py,

for the testing iteself see https://github.com/roya0045/cvar2/blob/master/test2.py )

Comment: What’s the error?

Comment: You have to include code, else nobody can tell you much.

Comment: @LukeDinh there is no error message but all weights are the same after the training process. So comparing the weights and bias before and after training yield only arrays of zeroes, which is not the case using cnn.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro the full layer implementation is located here https://github.com/roya0045/cvar2/blob/master/tfvar.py

Comment: Did you try looking at the output of tf.gradients(output, variables) where output = my_layer(input)? This will tell you whether the gradients are being computed correctly.